# NavBar color ios 7

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the color of the Navigation Bar to an Iphone app.

It works on ios 6 but it doesn't on ios 7

I have read that on ios 7 yo have to set the tint instead of the background and that is what I have done.

[image]

[image]

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works! But now I have another problem. The buttons were reds by default and now obviously they are not visible. Do I have to change their style by hand? Or is there a way of getting a "red bar style" or something?

Comment: if your button are just not label type then create the custom UIButton  and with that create the UIBarbutton and add to your navigation bar

Comment: And what can I do with the default back button? Create it myself?

Comment: Yes, create custom button and add for back button

Comment: No! Don't use `[[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion`. Use `floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` instead.

Comment: why? is there any reason for that?

Comment: @Retro apple seems to officially recommend it (see 'loading resources conditionally https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)

Of course yours is a valid method - you could use responsdToSelector also for example, but they're likely to more expensive processes/less efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Change color as you want.

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [UINavigationBar.appearance setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [UIToolbar.appearance setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}else{
    [UINavigationBar.appearance setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```